# Angular 7 fill Form Input

Tags: angular, forms

I have a problem with filling Data in Input in FormGroup.

I have a variable Company with a lot of data in it.

I make a formGroup with all this Data :

```
this.EditCoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      coid: ['', [Validators.required]],
      coname: ['', [Validators.required]],
      service: [null,],
      address: ['', [Validators.required]],
      state: ['', [Validators.required]],
      zip: ['', [Validators.required]],
      city: ['', [Validators.required]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      size: [null, [Validators.required]],
      domain: [null, [Validators.required]],
      duns: [null,],
      tid1: ['', [Validators.required]],
      numid1: ['', [Validators.required]],
      tid2: [null,],
      numid2: [null,],
      tid3: [null,],
      numid3: ['',],
      bankname: ['', [Validators.required]],
      bicswift: ['', [Validators.required]],
      iban: ['', [Validators.required]],
      bogid: [,[Validators.required]],
});
```

I want to put values from variable "Company" in EditCoForm and  the HTML text input fields.

```
<div class="form-field">
   <label class="text-white">ID</label>
   <br>
   <input formControlName="coid" value="company.coid">
</div>
```

On the HTML page, we have to value of "company.coid" but in EditCoForm on Submit it's ''.

**So How to process to put : (I'm noob in Angular)
"company" values in EditCoForm & in HTML Fields ?**

Thanks a lot for Help.

Comment: `[value]="company.coid"` this works ?

Comment: We have company.coid value in the input, but not the value in EditCoForm

Comment: see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-example-ocx9se  .value is in the input. isn't that what you want

Answer (score 2):

> I want to put values from variable "Company" in EditCoForm and the HTML text input fields.

You need to put these values (from `company`) when creating form group:

```
// suppose company is
company = {
  coid: 'coid',
  coname: 'coname'
}

this.EditCoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  coid: [this.company.coid, [Validators.required]],
  coname: [this.company.coname, [Validators.required]],
  ...
```

Then, both the form controls with appropriate names and input values (in HTML template) will have values from `company`:

```
<form [formGroup]="EditCoForm">
  <div class="form-field">
  <label class="text-white">ID</label><br>
    <input formControlName="coid">
  </div>
 ...  

</form>
```

Or, if it's not possible to do when creating form group, you can also set values for form group in this way:

```
this.EditCoForm.setValue({
  coid: this.company.coid,
  coname: this.company.coname,
  ...

});
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-fill-form-input-stackoverflow)

Comment: thanks for your help, but it's doesn't work all the way : With New Formcontrol, it's ok the values are in EditcoForm, but there is nothing in all the input text fields. I have errors on all input fields :  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: @BenYsil where in your component do you create form group by calling `this.EditCoForm = this.formBuilder.group`? The most common reason for this error is trying to access form group at the moment when it's not yet created. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-fill-form-input-stackoverflow-gdjasg) I've created from after some time in `ngOnInit` and it gives this error, because in html I''m trying to access controls of form when it's not yet created (form is undefined)

Comment: Yes i got the error with formBuilder. I make this with Formgroup, and make it in ngOnInit. and it works.